# Wget returns images in an unknown format (jpg@f=)

Tags: regex, wget

I am running the following line:

```
wget -P "C:\My Web Sites\REGEX" -r --no-parent -A jpg,jpeg https://www.mywebsite.com/directory1/directory2/
```

and it stops (no errors) without returning more than a small amount of the website (two files). I am then running this:

```
wget -P "C:\My Web Sites\REGEX"  https://www.mywebsite.com/directory1/directory2/ -m
```

and expecting to see data only from the directory. As a start, I found out that the script downloaded everything from the website as if I gave the `https://www.mywebsite.com/` url. Also, the images are returned with an additional string in the extension (e.g. instead of `.jpg` I get something like `.jpg@f=l=q`)

Is there anything wrong in my code that causes that? I only want to get the images from the links that are shown in the directory given initially.

If there is nothing I can change, then I want to only download the files that contain `.jpg` in their names. Then, I have a prepared script in Python that can rename the files to have the original extension.  Worst case, I can try Python instead of the CMD in Windows (page scraping)?

Note that `--no-parent` doesn't work in this case because the images are saved in a different directory. `--accept-regex` can be used if there is no way to get the correct extension.

PS: I do this thing in order to learn more about the wget options and protect my future hobby website.

UPD: Any suggestions regarding a Python script are welcome.

Comment: Not a programming question, try e.g. superuser.com.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt A solution can be a Python script. A script using Beautifulsoup for instance?

Comment: Sure, many problems can be solved using a program. However, it's not clear where the actual error is and whether it isn't just the webserver providing data you just don't like.

Comment: The images are returned with a dirty extension. It should be jpg but it returns jpg@f= and then a number. I double-checked that they don't have this extension in the server.